# Using Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory and PublishPipelineArtifact in a Matrix Build

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-tasks

My Azure Pipelines build outputs NuGet packages in the `/home/vsts/work/1/Windows` folder where `Windows` is a matrix name (I'm running the build section of my pipeline on Windows, Mac and Linux but want to publish the NuGet packages only from my Windows build).

The docs talk about using the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg` path to pass to `NuGetCommand@2`. However, this points to the `/home/vsts/work/1/a` folder.

Is the `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` variable wrong because I'm using a matrix build? Is it wrong because I'm using the `PublishPipelineArtifact@0` task to publish my .nupkg's?

Here [is a link to my azure-pipelines.yml file](https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Schema.NET/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the `matrix` strategy with `PublishArtifacts`, you have multiple artifacts, so in the second stage (the deployment stage) the 3 artifacts are downloaded not to folder `a` in the agent, but to the root build folder:

```sh
    home
    |-- vsts
      |-- work
        |-- 1
          |-- a
              b
              s
              Test Results
              Mac
              Ubuntu
              Windows
```

So you need to combine the variable `$(Build.BuildDirectory)` (`home/vsts/work/1`) with `/Windows/.nupkg`, like so:

```
$(Build.BuildDirectory)/Windows/.npukg
```